# Sending SPL token with NextJS/ReactJS and @solana/wallet-adapter-react

Tags: spl-token, solana-wallet-adapter

Does anyone have a boilerplate / example of sending a SPL token with @solana/wallet-adapter-react? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the wallet adapter dapp example at https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/master/APP.md and change the transaction to use spl token instead.

This could look like:

```
import { createTransferInstruction } from '@solana/spl-token';

...

        const transaction = new Transaction().add(
            createTransferInstruction(
                sourceAccount, // the token account to send from
                destinationAccount, // the token account to send to
                owner, // the owner of sourceAccount
                transferAmount, // the number of tokens to transfer
            )
        );
```