How to transfer spl token using wallet-adapter or any other wallet like phantom wallet?
Almost all of the tutorial and materials online/guide uses keypair, which is not practical

The transaction process remains consistent with the examples you've seen in tutorials. The key distinction lies in how the transaction is signed and sent.
Here's an example in React using the WalletAdapter
import { WalletNotConnectedError } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-base";
import { useConnection, useWallet } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import { Keypair, SystemProgram, Transaction } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, createTransferInstruction } from "@solana/spl-token";
import React, { FC, useCallback } from "react";

export const SendSPLTokenToAddress: FC = (
  fromTokenAccount,
  toTokenAccount,
  fromWallet
) => {
  const { connection } = useConnection();
  const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = useWallet();

  const onClick = useCallback(async () => {
    if (!publicKey) throw new WalletNotConnectedError();

    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
      createTransferInstruction(
        fromTokenAccount.address,
        toTokenAccount.address,
        fromWallet.publicKey,
        1,
        [],
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
      )
    );

    const signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection);

    await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, "processed");
  }, [publicKey, sendTransaction, connection]);

  return (
    <button onClick={onClick} disabled={!publicKey}>
      Send 1 lamport to a random address!
    </button>
  );
};

If you're following any tutorial, replace sendAndConfirmTransaction or sendRawTransaction, as shown in the tutorial, with the sendTransaction from the useWallet hook.

your code is for sol transfer, im specifically looking for spl token, not able to get past creating associated token accounts

This is actually for SPL tokens. This question was for using the WalletAdapter. So you can ask another question on the issue you're having with sending SPL tokens

You can also take a look at this: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5149/sending-spl-token-with-nextjs-reactjs-and-solana-wallet-adapter-react
